# MySQL, tuples related by field on same table, GROUP BY or SELF JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have these tables (simplified):

```
Appointment(
    INT idAppointment,
    DATETIME start,
    DATETIME end)

AppointmentInvolved(
    INT idAppointment,
    INT idInvolved)

Involved(
    INT idInvolved,
    VARCHAR name,
    INT type,
    INT idIncident)

Incident(
    INT idIncident,
    VARCHAR description)
```

There has been an Incident, possibly several Involved on it. Each Involved can have more than one Appointment, and each Appointment can be attended by more than one Involved. Involved have types (principal=1, secondary=2 for this example).

Given an idAppointment I need to know the principal Involved in that Incident, no matter if he's going to attend that specific Appointment.

So far:

```
SELECT(*)
FROM Appointments a
INNER JOIN (AppointmentInvolved ai) ON ai.idAppointment = a.idAppointment,
INNER JOIN (Involved i) ON i.idInvolved = ai.idInvolved,
INNER JOIN (Incident in) ON i.idIncident = in.idIncident,
WHERE a.idAppointment = <WHATEV>
WHERE in.type=1
```

That obviously won't work unless the principal involved is going to attend that appointment.
Is that some kind of self-join? I don't really need the Incident table, because the Involved persons can be related by idInvolved directly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Involved I
WHERE I.type=1 
  AND I.idIncident IN (SELECT I2.idIncident 
                       FROM AppointmentInvolved AI
                          INNER JOIN Involved I2 ON AI.idInvolved = I2.idInvolved
                          WHERE AI.idAppointment=<WHATEV>)
```

Comment: What if I needed more fields of the appointment? How can I select them and still get the WHERE IN statement to work?

Comment: You would need use you initial SELECT statement but replace with WHERE clause with the one from my answer.